# Vector Multiplication using GPU on python

Tags: python, gpu, vector-multiplication

I'm trying to do vector multiplication using numba vectorize. But instead of having two lists containing int or float type, i have two lists containing objects. I want to do multiplication of the attributes contained in these objects. ie. ob1.attr * ob2*attr where ob1 and ob2 are lists of size N. How do you do this?

Comment: Also if anyone knows how to use numbapro vectorise can anyone explain how to change the type to accept a class instead of float32. For example I have the function that does vector multiplication to accept type Class instead of only accepting float32

Comment: I doubt it supports using anything but native types. Either way, the numbers would have to be moved into a continuous array for the gpu.

Comment: I'm working in python so i'm using lists. Is there another way to do fast vector mathematics in python without having to just use native types?

Comment: numpy,numexpr,pycuda,pyopencl,numba (and probably more than i don't know of) all can do fast vector mathemtics. but they all also require the data to be in some form of array\matrix. it's a fundamental requirement for the data to be continious in memory for it to be fast.